When I submit a form using post method in nodejs,the page keeps on loading with no response and a 304 error in nodejs server
Im a beiginner in nodejs,and while I was doing a an web-application using nodejs suddenly this error comes and I trie my best still didnt got what's the problem
Here is my code:
app.js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var hbs=require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();
var fileUpload=require('express-fileupload')
var db=require('./config/connection')
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({extname:'hbs',runtimeOptions: {
  allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
  allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
},defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'})) 
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(fileUpload());
db.connect(()=>{
  if(err)
  console.log("Connection Error"+err);
else
console.log("Database Connected");
})
app.use('/', userRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;

admin.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var productHelpers=require('../helpers/product-helpers');
var path = require('path')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  productHelpers.getAllProducts().then((products)=>{
    //console.log(products)
  res.render('admin/view_products',{admin:true,products})
});
})
router.get('/add-product',function(req,res){
res.render('admin/add-product')
})
router.post('/add-product',function(req,res){
//console.log(req.body);  
if (req.files.Image ? console.log(req.files.Image) : "no image")
//console.log(req.files.Image);
productHelpers.addProduct(req.body,(id)=>{
  console.log(id)
  //console.log(req.body)
  let image=req.files.Image
 // console.log(image)
  //image.mv('./public/product-images/'+id+'.jpg',(err,done)=>{
    const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/product-images', `${id}.jpg`);
    image.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {
    if(!err){
      res.redirect('/admin')
    }else{
      res.send("no imagesssssss")
    }
  })
 
})
})
module.exports = router;

view_products.js
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <a href="/admin/add-product" class="btn btn-success ml-auto">Add Product</a>
        </div>
        <table class="table mt-5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">NO</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Category</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th>Image</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each products}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>{{this.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.Category}}</td>
      <td>{{this.Description}}</td>
      <td><img style="width:50px;height:50px" src="/public/images/{{this._id}}" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</section>

add-products
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="text-center">Add Product</h2>
                <form action="/admin/add-product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="">Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">

                <label for="">Category</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Category" class="form-control">

                 <label for="">Price</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Price" class="form-control">

                 <label for="">Description</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Description" class="form-control">

                <label for="Image">Image</label>
                 <input type="file" name="Image" class="form-control">

                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

product-helpers
const { resolve } = require('path');
const db = require('../config/connection')
const {connect} = require('../config/connection')
const collection = require('../config/collection');


module.exports = {
    addProduct:async (product, callback) => {
       try {  console.log('Adding product:', product);
        const db = await connect();
        const collection = db.collection('products'); // Access the collection
         await collection.insertOne(product).then((data)=>{
          // console.log(data);
         // Insert the document
        
        console.log('Product added');
        callback(data._insertedId); // Pass the result to the callback, success
    })}
        // Ensure the database connection is available
    
            catch(err) {
                console.error('Failed to add product:', err);
                callback(err); // Pass the error to the callback
            }
    },
    getAllProducts:()=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            let products= await db.getDb().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).find().toArray()
            resolve(products)
        })
    }
}

enter image description here
I tried clearing the cache, but it was not useful. Any ideas why this error occurs. It was working fine before but suddenly this error comes. I have been trying to solve it for more than 3 days still didn't get solution, anyone can help me

HTTP status 304 is not an error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304 What do you expect to happen, when if (req.files.Image ? console.log(req.files.Image) : "no image") is false? The server doesn't send a response to the browser. req.files.Image ? console.log(req.files.Image) : "no image" returns undefined when req.files.Image is truthy. undefined is falsy.

thanks,removing that block solved the problem
